Docusign Integration with power page
enter image description hereenter image description hereI have created a multistep form so I am not able to understand step-2 of multistep form in that I have added the consent part and done setting of adding template. I have doubt that we have to add list on our own where we get button and on click of that button my Document will open or what to do.
I have created a multistep form and integrated docusign but I am not able to understand after doing that also my docusign document is not opening

Can you share the API call you're making? what error do you get? any screenshots?

yes like when I integrate docuSign template in my multistep for I got the error"We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again, and if this persists, contact the website administrator."

This error is not DocuSign error, but PowerApps error, may want to consult with PowerApps documentation, if you want to build an integration directly using APIs - we can help.

Can you try again? there was a fix done by Microsoft today that may (not sure) be the reason for this error

Based on the screenshot and error message, this error is occurring on the PowerApps side I recommend checking the PowerApps documentation or with their team. We can help if you need to use DocuSign APIs to build the integration.
Also on Microsoft Power Platform, they have documentation about the DocuSign connector: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/docusign/
